# Git and add -p problems

Tags: git, whitespace, git-add, git-patch, git-stage

I have just applied a `patch` to 3 files, their `diff` can be seen here:

[**stack.h**](https://pastebin.com/DTncCN8Z), [**stack.c**](https://pastebin.com/67NLGSRQ) and [**main.c**](https://pastebin.com/V3Dq4DyT).

The task is to separate the `patch` into various `commit`s, like comments, license, refactoring etc.

For that I will use `git add -p`:

1. First hunk is license of `main.c`, trivial, i press `y`.
2. Second hunk is in `stack.c` and contains one hunk of license followed by two hunks of comments. I `s`plit and then `y` `n` `n`
3. I will keep doing this for the rest of `git add -p`.

HOWEVER, it looks like none of the `n` applied!

To confirm my suspicions I will do a fresh `git add -p` again, this time I will use `e` and [**this**](https://pastebin.com/b51m2RH7) will become [**this**](https://pastebin.com/J3KjhtEh).

`git` then outputs `fatal: corrupt patch at line 50`. So basically my `s` and `n` tried to not stage certain hunks but ended up discarding those removals.

`+` lines should be removed without problems unlike `-` (where you have to replace that line with space), right? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not follow `git add -p` + `git commit` at each step. Saying "no" with `n` means that the remaining changes haven't been staged. You need to repeat `git add -p` followed by `git commit` for each type of change that you want to appear in each commit.

> HOWEVER, it looks like none of the n applied!

This is by design. It means you did not want that in the index. So the changes were not staged. When you commit, they will not be part of that commit. You must repeat the process to get /those/ in like the previous iteration.

You are done with `git add -p` + `git commit` iterations once there are no more outstanding changes to commit.

Again, the hunks you say "no" to with `n` will NOT be part of the commit you make with `git commit`.

It may be that you need to read up on how git's staging (or index) works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I use `git add -p` and that starts showing me hunks where I will have various options (`y, n, q, a` etc.). I make my choice and then next hunk comes, until no more hunks are available, then I would `commit`. But the problem is that I'm not gonna `commit` since I only wanted this commit to add license, not comments. That's why I excluded everything but license.

Comment: it won't, it'll only add the hunks you said yes to. Next time around, the hunks you said yes to and committed, won't show up when you do the `git add -p`. You repeat this cycle until you have committed all your changes.

Comment: Ohhhh, so when I `cat` files and there are the changes already "applied", they have only been changed locally and I can split those changes into `commit`s, right?

Comment: Besides Adam's (correct) answer, you might want to read up on using `git diff --cached` to compare what's in the *index* right now (the selectively-staged parts) to what's in the `HEAD` (current) commit right now. That shows you what would be different in a commit you make *right now* with `git commit`, i.e., the difference between the HEAD files and the index files.